# sqliteSQLiteException: near "group"

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_BARS_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_INVENTORY+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                +KEY_CATEGORY+" TEXT, "
                +KEY_GROUP+" TEXT, "
                +KEY_SERIAL+" TEXT, "
                +KEY_BUYING_PRICE+" REAL, "
                +KEY_UNIT_PRICE+" REAL, "
                +KEY_DATE_ADDED+" TEXT "+")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BARS_TABLE);
    }
```

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "group": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE inventory (id INTEGER
>   PRIMARY KEY, category TEXT, group TEXT, serial TEXT, buyingprice REAL,
>   unitprice REAL, dateAdded TEXT )
>                                                                              at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)

Answer (score 4):

`group` is a [reserved keyword in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Use backticks to escape the name

```
`group` TEXT, ...
```

or choose another column name.

Answer (score 1):

**group** is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as an column name. You can change this.